# Is json and map the same in dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am working on json mapping in c# but i couldn't match in dart.

I was working with json data in dart. Because I was using SQFLite, I started working with map. I couldn't quite understand the difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

A Map is a dictionary, and can have key-value pairs of any type.
For example, `{"String": int}`, `{int: List<String}` etc.
A JSON can only have key types of String.
For example, `{"String": int}`, NOT `{int: ___}`

JSONs and Maps are also indexed the same, for example `Map<String, String> map = {"brand": "Nothing", "model": "Phone(1)"}`
to get "Nothing", you would reference `map["brand"]`, the same as with JSON.

In this way, it is the same as a JSON, and looks almost identical.

So to answer your question, no they are not the same, and will need to be converted between each other - but for all intents and purposes you can think of them as the same thing.